# APA citation: book versus electronic book

Tags: writing

I obtain many of my reading sources from online, instead of form a hardcopy in the library, even for books or book sections. The APA citation requirements for citing printed books and citing e-books are different. If my source IS indeed an e-book, I wonder whether I should really cite e-books according to the e-book citation requirement, which includes URL and all kinds of extra information than citing a printed book. Can I just cite it as if it is from a printed book?

Answer (score 2):

Do not take it for granted that different versions of a book are identical.

Either cite the version you've used, or use the version you want to cite.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the different citation information for e-books is to deal with the fact that some purely electronic books are much more mutable that electronic books.

In your case, however, you are dealing with a persistent, expected immutable document that just happens to have been delivered to you in a more efficient manner.  Therefore, it is appropriate to cite it as an ordinary book, just as when you are citing a journal article, you don't have to say whether you obtained a paper copy or a PDF.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense! but do you mind giving me an example for a more 'mutable' case?

Comment: @FayeClassie, until recently, Amazon's Kindle books didn't have page numbers that tied back to the same page numbers in the hard-copy editions. All you could get was a nebulous "position".